# How to make my project runnable on any system?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005

I have developed a solution in Visual Studio 2008 C# WPF!
I'm using a service-base SQL database (I've created and managed using Microsoft Visual Studio Sever Explorer), now I'm going to publish it but the problem is that when I install .NET Framework 4.0 and SQLEXPRESS 2005 on other systems, my application doesn't launch! :-(
What componenets should I install on the systems to make it runnable?

Comment: think you might need to install .Net 3.5

Comment: 3.5 SP1 is included in the .NET 4 installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you develop with Visual Studio 2008 you will probably need to install .NET Framework 3.5 with Service Pack 1.

If that is not enough you need to post the error you get. Probably in the eventviewer you will see more info.
You can try to create a setup using Clickonce. To do this you need to go to the property pages of the WPF project an go to the tab Publish.
There you can choose to publish it to the network or to a local directory which can be put on a CD or USB device. The most important thing for you to check is the button "Prerequisites".

I hope this helps!

EDIT to help with the comments:

[image]

It is perfectly possible to put the prerequisites in the same folder as the install or even better in a fixed network location as you can see in this screenshot below

Comment: Thanks Wouter, I tried Publish but it gives me an error when I try to install it on a system with Windows XP installed!
The error is:
"System Update Required
Unable to install or run application. The application requires that assembly WindowsBase Verision 3.0.0.0 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first."
So what's the problem? Is there any other ways to make a compatible installer for it?
Thanks.

Comment: I ran setup.exe and it is working! :-). But there is still something, when it is installing the application it donwloads the required things (like .NET Framework) from the internet..is there any way to include every needed component on the installer file so that nothing will be downloaded? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think VS has that option to include what's necessary. However, you might want to check out the homepage for the .NET Framework, or possibly contact MS about it. Maybe you're allowed to download it and distribute it along with your applications. I'd check first though.

Comment: @MOLi - There is; I don't have VS2008 installed anymore so cannot guide you through the steps, but the properties of a setup project, in the dependencies area, allow to specify whether to download them or get them from the filesystem. I think that not every component can be configured like that (for instance, .Net Framework 3.5 Client Profile must be downloaded for sure), but I've done that some years ago so I can tell you it works.

Comment: I hope that my edited answer helps you to solve your problem?

Comment: Also, keep in mind, if you upgrade you project to 4.0 anytime. Remember to mark the CPU type as x86. HTH

Comment: It did work...I made a 'Setup and Deployment' project and made everything ok. Thanks in advance.:-)